# Can't change background on navi bar bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried so hard to edit my styles every single element but NOTHING will change my navigation bar's background. I've tried editing literally every single element that could be in the navi bar but literally nothing will change. I've tried editing it by using the rule "#navbar .navbar-nav" but whenever i click background color it goes back to transparent... WHAT AM I DOING WRONG????

HTML:

```
<header role="banner">
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img id="logo-navbar-middle" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/32877/logo-thing.png" width="200" alt="Logo Thing main logo"></a></li>
    <li></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
</header><!-- header role="banner" -->
</body>
```

And my styles:

```
#navbar .navbar-nav { 
//  background: #FFFFFF;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;

> .nav.navbar-nav li {
display: inline-block;
float: none;
> .nav.navbar-nav a {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;

}
;   
background-color: #000000;
}
}

}
#navbar-primary-collapse .nav.navbar-nav li {
color: #FFFF;
padding-left: 30px;
padding-right: 30px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.container-fluid .navbar-header .navbar-toggle {
background-color: #FFFFFF;

}
li a #logo-navbar-middle {

}
.nav.navbar-nav li a {
padding-left: 30px;
padding-right: 30px;
text-align: center;
color: #000000;
text-transform: uppercase;
float: none;
display: inline-block;
padding-left: 30px;
padding-right: 30px;
text-align: center;
color: #000000;
text-transform: uppercase;
float: none;
display: inline-block;}
.nav.navbar-nav li  {
float: none;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO :) the color is changing for the #navbar element. a fiddle will help in zeroing in on the issue :)

Comment: Your CSS is either not CSS but SASS or equivalent or it's just not valid CSS. Better formatting may help us understand what you're doing, too.

Answer (score 2):

**css**

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

and make sure that, your css file is loaded after bootstrap css

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't declared the nav correctly in your CSS. Try the following:

```
#navbar.navbar-default {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

You'd separated `#navbar` and `.navbar-default` even though they are attached to the same element.

Alternatively, add another class and style it this way:

```
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar-default navbar-custom" role="navigation">
```

And then target it as follows:

```
#navbar.navbar-custom {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Since bootstrap.css just styles the class as `.navbar-default {}` and assuming your CSS is loaded after BootStrap's, the above will override BS's since it is more specific and is loaded afterwards.

You could even just remove the class `navbar-default` altogether if you like and add your own border / background from scratch instead of overriding.

Comment: @JacobNeyenhuis No problem - please accept an answer as correct if it helps you - it may help others in the future.